# Redirect to another path in Node JS route

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node Js route.js when user try to open

`app.use('/demo1', require('express').static(__dirname + '/demo1'));`

then i want to redirect to

`app.use('/demo2', require('express').static(__dirname + '/demo2'));`

like
In the browser user type
http://locahhost:5010/demo1 this URL

but it will open 
http://locahhost:5010/demo2 this URL

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use redirect in your route [Express redirect](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect)

Example:

```
app.get('/demo1', function(req, res) {
 res.redirect('/demo2');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
 if (req.url == '/') {
  res.redirect('/en');
  return;
 }
  next();
})
```

I was thru the same and i had to use return next() was calling before

Answer (score 1):

You probably created a route. To fix, change the about router from this:

```
app.get('/demo1', function(req, res) {
 res.redirect('/demo2');
});
```

You can try this is as well if you have routes in seperate files. Let say we have it in demo1route.js in the route folder.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();    
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.render('/demo2');
});
```

and then use below code in app.js

```
var demo1 = app.require('../demo1route.js')    
app.use('/demo1',demo1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/demo1', function(req, res) {
 res.redirect('/demo2');
});
```

this should work fine if /demo2 is a get request router